# Which is the easiest International currency to exchange?

Tags: foreign-exchange

What is the best currency to exchange when travelling? Is it the **US Dollar**, the **Euro** or the **British Pound**? One that gets accepted everywhere and which is unlikely to get rejected because it's too old, or because of some defects that make them charge commission.

Comment: Where are you going? The answer is different in different parts of the world.

Comment: To Uganda, and then to Malaysia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the **US Dollar** and the **Euro** are generally well accepted by a lot of countries while travelling. The **British Pound** is less common but still accepted by a lot of countries. US Dollar is also well accepted in Uganda (2006 +).

I would suggest you **US Dollar** or **Euro**.

You should read this : https://www.matoketours.com/practical-info/uganda/uganda/